# How to change styles of a component dynamically using widgetwar?

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to make Notification Bar to hide automatically.
I mean we can do that using JavaScript.
But is Primefaces providing any other functionality to do that?

And I also want to know the way to change Styles to widget in JavaScript.

for Example

```
<p:notificationBar widgetVar="notify" />
```

I can use

```
notify.show() and notify.hide()
```

but how to change styles like background color, in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access CSS as follows:

```
jQuery(notify.jq).css();
```

Use `css()` function according to jQuery reference manual.